# JavaScript code don't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a code which works in Chrome and Firefox but does not in Safari.

Here is a code:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("navigation1");
var already_moved = 0;
menu.onmouseover = function moveNavigation(menu) {
    if (already_moved == 0) {
        document.getElementById("navigation1").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        already_moved = 1;
    }
};

menu.onmouseleave = function moveBackNavigation(menu) {
    if (already_moved == 1) {
        //document.getElementById("navigation1").style.marginLeft = "-341px";
        closeMenu();
        already_moved = 0;
    }
};

function closeMenu(){
    setTimeout(function f(){
        document.getElementById("navigation1").style.marginLeft = "-341px";
        already_moved = 0;
        }, 2000);
};
```

This code moves menu to left and back.
Thanks for any ideas - how to make it works in Safari.

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: I use Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)

Comment: How does it not work in Safari? Not at all or does it do something unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify that you did actually enable JavaScript within Safari, right? [As shown here](http://activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/safari).